# iptables REJECT with delay

Tags: iptables, icmp

Simulating an unreachable host:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.42 -j REJECT
```

And then `ping 192.168.1.42`.

It rejects immediately, so the terminal is flooded with `Destination Port Unreachable`. How to add a delay to the REJECTs, so it would look more natural?

Comment: Maybe `-m limit --limit 3/minute` for REJECT and DROP the rest. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux

Comment: BTW if it's just about `ping` you could use limit this instead `ping -i 20 192.168.1.42`